# Synching progress in podcasts not synched correctly

Tags: podcasts, podcasts.app

I often listen to podcasts in my car via the dock connector and the cars stereo as well as via headphones (when I'm mowing the lawn, for example). However, I think ever since the Apple podcasts app got updated to 2.1, the position as well as marking a podcast 'played' isn't syncing very well. For example I'll completely listen to a podcast in the car, but after I get home the circle will only be half empty.

What mechanism is it that the phone uses to know how podcasts have been listened to via the dock connector?  Is this something I can fix with a new podcast app on the phone?

I've been doing it this way since my 3GS and only over the past few weeks has it gotten really bad to the point I've listened to the same intro segment of a podcast 5 times because the in progress marker doesn't "save" itself correctly when I turn the car off.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have also noticed that if I start `podcast A` with the headphones, then start `podcast B` in the car via the dock connector, and then later look under `now playing` on the phone, it will show `podcast A`, forgetting anything that was played in the car.